# Powershel copy a part of filename for variables

Tags: powershell

I need to copy a part of a file name and make it become a variable, for example my file is called "test-123456.txt" I need the variable $ part = 123456
clearly this inserted in a loop where the part of the file name "test" is always the same but the part "123456" changes.

Comment: How, exactly, are files named? Split on dash works for the sample, but are there more?

Comment: How are you getting the file as well? Could be something as simple as: `".Split("-")[1]`.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Try using below as a minimal example to play with but my also solve your problem.

```
$files = @('C:\fileName_12345.txt','C:\fileName_54321.txt')

foreach ($file in $files) {
  $varName = $file.split("/[ \w-]+\./g")[1]

  Write-Host "'varName' is the variabled named $varName...use it well"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This my part of script to better understand

```
$complist = Get-Content "F:\Source\complist3.txt"
foreach($comp in $complist)
{ 
    
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
    Remove-Item -Path "\\$comp\c$\Users\use1\AppData\Local\Programs\Update\*.zip" -Force
    Move-Item -Path "\\$comp\c$\Users\use1\AppData\Local\Programs\config\General123456.json" -Destination "\\$comp\c$\Users\Use1\AppData\Local\Programs\Update\General123456.json" -Force
    #IN  THIS POINT NEED CREATE A VARIABLE FOR COPY 123456 FROM General123456.json
    New-Item "\\$comp\c$\UpdateNH\" -ItemType Directory -Force
    New-Item "\\$comp\c$\UpdateNH\Source" -ItemType Directory -Force
    New-Item "\\$comp\c$\UpdateNH\log" -ItemType Directory -Force
    Copy-Item -Path $pathfilelocale -Destination "\\$comp\c$\UpdateNH\Source" -force
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock { 
    ########FOLDER 2##
    if (Test-Path $using:path2) 
    { 

    Add-Type -Path "C:\UpdateNH\Source\WinSCPnet.dll"
function FileTransferProgress
{
    param($e)
 
    Write-Progress `
        -Activity "Downloading" -Status ("{0:P0} complete:" -f $e.OverallProgress) `
        -PercentComplete ($e.OverallProgress * 100)
    Write-Progress `
        -Id 1 -Activity $e.FileName -Status ("{0:P0} complete:" -f $e.FileProgress) `
        -PercentComplete ($e.FileProgress * 100)

}
####SESSIONE#####
$script:lastFileName = $Null
try
{
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = $using:ftp
    UserName = "user"
    Password = "psw"
}
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
try
{
    #Report
    $session.add_FileTransferProgress( { FileTransferProgress($_) } )
    
    #Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    #Download
    $session.GetFiles("$using:folderagg*", "$using:targetzip2").Check()
    }
finally
{
    #Terminate line
    if ($script:lastFileName -ne $Null)
    {
        Write-Host
    }
    
    #Disconnect
    $session.Dispose()
}

########INSTALLAZIONE########
Expand-Archive $using:sourcezip2 -DestinationPath $using:target2 -Force
# IN THIS POINT I NEED OPEN Generl987456.json and replace a specific string with variable create before 123456
# IN THIS POINT I NEED RENAME General987456.json to General+variable123456+.json
#
# All pc in complist have a different name in Generalxxxxxx.json 
Start-Transcript $using:logfolder2\$using:comp.txt -Append
Write-Host "Aggiornameno effettuato il $using:date"
Stop-Transcript
shutdown -r /t 10

    exit 0
}
catch
{
Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```